# Unlimited scrolling via an accordion

Tags: accordion, infinite-scroll

I have two panels on the right side of the search page where I am splitting it by an accordion. Now, I am struggling with is that whether we should pursue infinite scrolling or pagination in this layout:

[image]

As you can see that my accordion is fluid, so with the flick of a button/finger(mobile) it can go on top and at the bottom based on what you would like to see.

**TOP RIGHT PANEL:** Shows you the listings on what you have selected on the left search with **infinite scrolling.**

**BOTTOM RIGHT PANEL:** Shows you a broader search with **infinite scrolling.**

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 2):

**A good approach is [Lean UX](http://www.uie.com/articles/why_lean_ux/).**

Sketch both solutions and then run it by a few users. *Let users guide your design*.

Since you have some tasks outlined already, a [cognitive walkthrough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_walkthrough) is probably going to be the best test to start. Listen/watch for comments relating to task completion, time on task, errors, efficiency, learnability, perceived severity of issues ([more](http://www.usertesting.com/blog/2013/03/29/what-to-test/)). Having these in mind will help keep your interviews focused and actionable.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to go with the pagination because the right side has 2 panels. The user has a clear idea on what action is being performed. In case of infinite scrolling, some times the second panel action might trigger scrolling.

As [@ken](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/10767/ken) suggested, I recommend Lean UX, it's the best way to approach this kind of issue.